# Scraping a web page by using XPath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping some web pages in order to get some information. I'm using Scrapy and XPath language.

This is an example of page I would get. In the page there are many of this li element

```
<li ckIgnore="false"   codmod="3857" ccar="A" area="NEW" versArea="NEW" shorturl="1" modurl="/auto">
<article>
    <a href=""><img width="210" height="158" src="" alt="" modello=></a>

    <img src="" alt="logo" class="logo-listing" width="38">

    <div class="hgroup">
        <a href="">
            <h5>ABARTH</h5>
            <h3>500 cabrio</h3> 

        </a>
    </div>
</article>
</li>
```

I'm using this syntax to get all the divs which have hgroup class. Unfortunately when I try to print print out models variable this is empty.

```
def parse(self, response):

    sel = Selector(response)
    models = sel.xpath("//div[@class='hgroup']/a")
```

Comment: Do you mean: `models == []` ?

Comment: yes exactly If I print models in python print models I got []

Comment: please print response as raw HTML:  `print response.body` .

Comment: I have already done it...I get all the html body of the page

Comment: @kev do you have any idea? if you want, I can show you the entire page

Comment: Check if there is a namespace xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` declaration (probably in `<html>`). If there is one, you will need to either *register* a prefix to qualify your selectors, or not use tag names as selectors in your XPath expressions (by using `//*[local-name()='div']/*[local-name()='a']` for example).

Comment: No there is not any namespace...

Comment: Do you think I should use BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that what scrapy "sees" is different than what you see on your browser. Try using `scrapy shell "http://example.com"` and check the `response.body` if what your looking for is there.